# How to translate the labels in your order in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having a problem on how to translate the labels in `YOUR ORDER` in `woocommerce`. I install a plugin that would translate my website from `English` to `Netherlands`, if I click to `Netherlands` I am not able to translate the labels and I can't find an error to it. For example: `TOTAL` in English then in Netherlands it is `TOTAAL`, then I am not able to translate it. Could somebody help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method. I am using `Spanish` as an example.

Bring up `wp-config.php` in a text editor and look for the line:

```
define('WPLANG', 'es_ES');
```

This will give you your language identifier, in this case its `es_ES`

Go to `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/i18n/languages` and look for:

```
woocommerce-es_ES.po
```

Rename it with a `.txt` extension so you can edit it.

Add a pair of lines at the end for each form label translation. The first is the English that appears now, the second line is the translation in your language. For example:

```
msgid "Company Name"
msgstr "Nombre de compañía"
```

Change the file back to `.po` and download it to your hard drive.

Compile your .po to .mo using [this](http://po2mo.net/) tool:

The converted filename might be:

```
h5673b_woocommerce_es_ES.po
```

change it to

```
woocommerce-es_ES.po
```

Ensure you get the underscores and hyphens right.

Upload the .po to

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/i18n/languages
```

overwriting the file that was there.

If you have a page caching plugin, delete cached pages.

Comment: I tried the steps above but when I run my website nothing is change. The labels are still the same.